# HBITMAP to .net Bitmap through PInvoke

Tags: .net, pinvoke

i am trying to use unmanaged code from managed code

i would like to provide the following function from the unmanaged code

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport) HBITMAP *    DetectDocumentPatter(HBITMAP* b);
```

for now the implementation of the code just return the same parameter b

i am trying to access it from .net side

```
       1 Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Projects\samples\9b.jpg");
       2 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
       3 BitmapData bmpData = b.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);
       4 IntPtr p = wrapper.DetectDocumentPatter(bmpData.Scan0);
       5 Bitmap c = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(p);
       6 c.Save(@"C:\Projects\samples\unmanagedBitmap.jpg");
```

but the 5th line code through a generic error occured in GDI+

any idea how can i marshal HBITMAP to .net Bitmap ! 
i've searched here but the content is really misleading

Comment: The function signature is nonsensical, passing a HBITMAP* as an argument makes no sense.  And you are not passing a HBITMAP, that would require Bitmap.GetHbitmap().  And there's no error checking at all.  Contact the owner of this code to get help.